# how to use regexp_substr to trim and ignore dash

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

All my fields have a "-" character in it. I want to display only those before the "-" character... In addition, however, I would also like to restrict the length to display to 10 characters.  How do I do this with regexp or some other way?

```
select regexp_substr(field,'[^-]*') from dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do:

```
select substr(regexp_substr(field, '^[^-]*'), 10) from dual
```

The initial `^` is not really needed but it makes the pattern more strongly say "get the first sequence of non-dashes in the field".